# Which line defines the color?

Tags: assembly, x86

I've got this code in Assembly, which basically prints a grey message in the game.

Here's the code:

[image]

My question is **which line of code defines the grey color?**

Comment: From the code it sort of reminds me of `printf` family of functions, calling first some formatter with format string and values. Did you check the returned string value from `StringPool__GetString`, whether the format string doesn't contain some extra control characters to change colors? Like [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), or some custom scheme.

Comment: Another option is of course that the called routine *always* prints a grey string, and this code has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ (if anywhere because there's little evidence that this code has anything to do with color.)  But IDK, maybe the folks over there would enjoy this challenge of have something useful to say.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the `7` in this line:

```
mov byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 7
```

But that's just a wild guess, based on the fact that 7 used to be light grey in [CGA's 16-color palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#Color_palette).

The truth is, there is no way for us to tell what this code does just by staring at this tiny snippet of disassembly.
It's machine language; *everything* is represented by bits and bytes.
Not just colors, but also numbers, characters, shapes, geographical coordinates, dates, times, even code itself.
You'll have to figure out which is which.

I typically start with guessing (see above), and if that fails, I'll try a more thorough reverse-engineering effort.
Just follow the data; whatever byte ends up being injected into the relevant BIOS call or (memory-mapped) I/O address, must be the color.
This trail of data may be long and winding;
you will need to analyze a lot more code than just these few lines.

Comment: I have already tried modifying the '7' before I asked. How are colors defined in Assembly in general?

Comment: @Suspended they are not.

Comment: @Suspended: Then you should have said so in the question, so people would know what's already been tried.